# How do I go through a multidimensional array and add a value to each one?

Tags: php

```
I have an array that is like this:

array(3) {

[0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "10"
    ["name"]=>
    string(5) "city1"
  }

[1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "11"
    ["name"]=>
    string(5) "city2"
  }

[2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "12"
    ["name"]=>
    string(5) "city3"
  }

}
```

I need to add another value that's called "status" to **each** of them. So that it basically becomes:

```
     [0]=>
      array(3) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(2) "10"
        ["name"]=>
        string(5) "city1"
        ["status"]=>
        string(1) "1"
      }
```

The status is dynamic and may vary for each item, so I need to call a function like this:

```
$status = getStatus($id);
```

That `$id` I am getting also from each item in that array.

How would I do this best? I understand I need to loop through the array, but how do I then add each correct response from `getStatus` to the correct array item?

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33348090/looping-through-an-array-with-children-of-children/33348359#33348359

Comment: Thanks :) I know how to loop through it, but the problem is adding the new values :(

Comment: you should collect all statuses beforehand, then iterate through the array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this...

```
foreach($array $key=>$value){
   $array[$key]['status']=1;
}
```

[Demo......](http://phpio.net/s/1i1n)

Comment: Wow, that was super easy!

Answer (score 1):

I added a dummy function getStatus just to have an example, since you said that getStatus is dynamic might as well give you an example of that, you just have update to your own need of that function. Try this:

```
$data = 
  array(
      array(
        "id" => "10",
        "name" => "city1"
        ),
      array(
        "id" => "11",
        "name" => "city2"
        ),
      array(
        "id" => "13",
        "name" => "city3"
        )
    );
echo '<pre>';
    print_r($data);
echo '</pre>';


function getStatus($id) {
    if($id == "10") {
        $status = "1";
    } else if($id == "11") {
        $status = "2";
    } else if($id == "13") {
        $status = "3";
    }
    return $status;
}

foreach($data as $key => $values) {
    $data[$key]["status"] = getStatus($data[$key]["id"]);
}

echo '<pre>';
    print_r($data);
echo '</pre>';
```